# twisted serialport protocol

Tags: python, protocols, twisted

I have looked at the python twisted examples for using a serialport (gpsfix and mouse) and other solutions given here on stackoveflow. However, it still isn't clear how to write a general serial port protocol. Can anyone provide a simple (but complete) example of a python twisted SerialPort program?

I need to use /dev/ttySx as a serial port, and I need to both read an write from/to it.

Comment: What is "a general serial port protocol"?  What is not "general" about the examples you have seen already?

Comment: Maybe specific is a better word than 'general'. I need to use /dev/ttyS2 and have a protocol support both read and write from that port. The other examples come close, but it's not clear how to port that to use /dev/tty2 (or any other tty port).

Answer (score 2):

`SerialPort` accepts an argument that names the serial port for it to interact with.  It's the second argument, immediately follow the protocol argument.

For example,

```
from twisted.internet.serialport import SerialPort

port = SerialPort(yourProtocol, "/dev/tty2")
# ...
```